# Letsencrypt renew error(Ubuntu, Nginx, Node.js)

Tags: node.js, ubuntu, ssl, nginx, lets-encrypt

I inherited a configuration (Ubuntu, Nginx, Node.js, LetsEncrypt) where the letsencrypt certs are very near expiry.

I tried these commands:

`./letsencrypt-auto --renew --config /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.conf certonly`

`./letsencrypt-auto --renew --config /etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.conf -d domain.com -d www.domain.com`

Both cases received the following reply:
`letsencrypt: error: uir is a flag but is being set to 'None'`

I tried to change it to false or empty, but not working.

How is it possible to renew LetsEncrypt certs on this configuration?

Answer (score 3):

Try using simply `./letsencrypt-auto renew`.

It should read by itself the config file at `/etc/letsencrypt/renewal/domain.conf`.

Take a look at this tutorial (Step 4) to learn how it is renewed and how it is automated using `crontab`: 
[How to secure Nginx with Let's Encrypt on Ubuntu 14.04](https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-secure-nginx-with-let-s-encrypt-on-ubuntu-14-04)